# What is performance bottleneck of my Apache server?

Tags: web, apache-2.2, httpd, httpd.conf

I have too many requests waiting which can be seen from netstat as follows

```
$netstat -anp | grep :80 | grep TIME_WAIT | wc -l  
840 
$netstat -anp |grep :80 | grep ESTABLISHED | wc -l 
50
```

memory usage : 850MB / 1000MB

apache2.conf contains..

```
<IfModule mpm_prefork_module>
    StartServers          5
    MinSpareServers       5
    MaxSpareServers      10
    MaxClients          150
    MaxRequestsPerChild   0
</IfModule>

<IfModule mpm_worker_module>
    StartServers          2
    MinSpareThreads      25
    MaxSpareThreads      75
    ThreadLimit          64
    ThreadsPerChild      25
    MaxClients          150
    MaxRequestsPerChild   0
</IfModule>

<IfModule mpm_event_module>
    StartServers          2
    MaxClients          150
    MinSpareThreads      25
    MaxSpareThreads      75
    ThreadLimit          64
    ThreadsPerChild      25
    MaxRequestsPerChild   0
</IfModule>
```

Are there any configuration changes that can help me or its just my RAM the bottleneck here ?
Urgent help needed..!!

Comment: what is the current mpm configuration, prefork? worker?. And gives us any configuration concerning Keepalive and tiemout, check as well http://serverfault.com/questions/86550/apache-keep-alive-or-not-keep-alive for nice explanations on TIME_WAIT problem (which is not completly related to keep alive, but keepalive timeout is maybe your problem).

Answer (score 1):

You should start by checking out the mod_status module. It will show you much more information about what your Apache web server is doing.

There is documentation available at http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_status.html including an example of how to use it.