# Apache becomes unconnectable after certain time?

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-php

After maybe ~20 minutes it seems like my apache server becomes unconnectable. By unconnectable, I mean if I `curl` any page, it just results in nothing for 2-3 minutes and then nothing ever shows up. I'm forced to restart apache to make it usable. The actual box itself seems fine, since I'm always SSH'd in... so I think this is just an Apache thing.

After ~3-5 minutes of stopping/starting the apache server, memory usage twindles:

One second it's:

```
                                          CPU  MEM
21997 root      20   0  459m 208m 8504 R  45.8 20.8  10:14.56 apache2
```

The next:

```
21997 root      20   0  459m 208m 8504 S   8.8 20.8  10:37.37 apache2
```

So one second it's at 40% CPU, 20% mem

There are only 2-3 small websites that use PHP, so there's no way they could be consuming that amount of memory. I'm wondering why this happens?!

My config for Apache (prefork) is:

```
<IfModule mpm_prefork_module>
    StartServers          5
    MinSpareServers       5
    MaxSpareServers      10
    MaxClients          150
    MaxRequestsPerChild   0
</IfModule>
```

Server version: Apache/2.2.22 (Debian)

On Debian Wheezy using `libapache2-mod-php5`

I know `mod_php` is probably not the most efficient and there might be better alternatives like `php-fpm`, and/or using `nginx` but I want to actually get at the root of the problem instead of avoiding it.

Would appreciate any tips.

The configuration for apache2 I believe is stock. Using DigitalOcean VPS, the 1GB Memory / 30 GB SSD / 2TB Transfer tier.

**EDIT #1**: I just read some Linode optimization article and it mentions turning `KeepAlive` off on low memory servers. I'm going to try this and see how it goes.

[Apache - keep-alive or not keep-alive?](https://serverfault.com/questions/86550/apache-keep-alive-or-not-keep-alive)

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked your logs? access.log and error.log?

Comment: Wow, must've had a brain freeze. It was My piped program for logs was failing. I think you got it!